# Get SQL ID on PHP page and pass it to another PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

Could anyone please help me to get the `ID` variable from SQL and send it to another PHP page?
`index.php` output: (Image1)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmV8j.png)

`checks.php` output:(Image2)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBSOH.png)

What I need to accomplish is the following:
Whenever I click on "OK" or "NOK" under status field in `index.php` page I need it to take me to another PHP page called `checks.php` and show me the `ID` of the line on which I clicked.

So for Example, on Image1 (which is the `index.php` page), if I click on *OK* under status column which has `ID=2`, I want to get this `ID` into variable and pass it to the next page `checks.php` to only show the line which has `ID=2` and not all `ID`'s within the table.

Here is my `index.php` code

```
<?php
    require_once('connection.php');
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM report");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['ElapsedTime']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['Computer']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['Manufacturer']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['ModelName']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['UserType']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['UserName']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><a href='checks.php?id=". urlencode($row['ID']) ."'><?php echo $row['Status']; ?></a></label></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Here is my `checks.php` code

```
<?php
    require_once('connection.php');
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM checks,report where checks.ID = report.ID and checks.ID = $id");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['WiFi']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['Printers']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['Notepad']; ?></label></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

If I manually set the `ID` such as http://localhost/checks.php?id=2, it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the last `td` row of your HTML code

```
<td><label><a href='checks.php?id=". urlencode($row['ID']) ."'><?php echo $row['Status']; ?></a></label></td>
```

As you can see you set the `href` of the `a` tag manually and try to add your PHP variable `$row['ID']` to it. Yet, you closed the PHP context a few lines before that, so you are in a HTML context, where you cannot access your PHP variable.

The solution is to open the PHP tag there again, just like you do afterwards with the `$row['Status']`. You also do not need to use `urlencode`, becuase the `ID` is numerical, so it will not be transformed anyways.

```
<td><label><a href='checks.php?id=<?= $row['ID'] ?>'><?= $row['Status'] ?></a></label></td>
```

I also used the short tags `<?= ... ?>` instead of `<?php echo '...' ?>`.